# How to execute PowerShell file in azure from terraform both from local and from azure

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform

I am wanting to execute a PowerShell file stored on Azure storage account from terraform both from locally and from azure.

I included provisioner on my terraform script to execute the PowerShell file

```
resource "azurerm_automation_account" "my_acc" {

  name                = "AUT-ACCOUNT-586"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg_obj.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg_obj.name}"
  sku_name  = "Basic"  

   provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "http://${azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.blobstorage.name}/Import-PowerShell-Modules.ps1"
    interpreter = ["PowerShell","-Command"]
  }
}
```

I expect the PowerShell file to get executed.

The output is The term 
'http://MyStorage.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/Import-PowerShell-Modules.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ http://MyStorage.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/Import-PowerShell ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (http://MyStorage...ell-Modules.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException. Getting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error which you got means the command that you use in the local-exec provisioner is not PowerShell command.

To execute the PowerShell script which stores locally. You can use the code like this:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "powershell -file ./test.ps1"
    }
```

You can use the relative path or absolute path of the file. And the command `powershell -file` shows here:

> ```
> -File
>     Runs the specified script in the local scope ("dot-sourced"), so that the
>     functions and variables that the script creates are available in the
>     current session. Enter the script file path and any parameters.
>     File must be the last parameter in the command, because all characters
>     typed after the File parameter name are interpreted
>     as the script file path followed by the script parameters.
> ```

So I would suggest if you want to execute the PowerShell script which stores in the Azure Storage account, you would better download the script or create a script locally to download the content of the script and execute it.